# How do I change this tikz picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I looked up and took a code to draw a cube but now I'm not able to centre it. I want to further divide the cube into smaller sections like this:
[image]

It's okay if I can draw just the lines instead of the minicubes to represent the division.
Here is my image:
[image]

I'm also not able to add labels to the image where I want them. I want to be able to provide labels for all three axes based on my requirement. Here is my code, could you help me out?

```
\newcommand{\Depth}{5}
\newcommand{\Height}{5}
\newcommand{\Width}{5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (0,\Width,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,\Width,\Height);
\coordinate (C) at (0,0,\Height);
\coordinate (D) at (\Depth,0,0);
\coordinate (E) at (\Depth,\Width,0);
\coordinate (F) at (\Depth,\Width,\Height);
\coordinate (G) at (\Depth,0,\Height);

\draw[] (O) -- (C) -- (G) -- (D) -- cycle;% Bottom Face
\draw[] (O) -- (A) -- (E) -- (D) -- cycle;% Back Face
\draw[] (O) -- (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;% Left Face
\draw[] (D) -- (E) -- (F) -- (G) -- cycle;% Right Face
\draw[] (C) -- (B) -- (F) -- (G) -- cycle;% Front Face
\draw[] (A) -- (B) -- (F) -- (E) -- cycle;% Top Face
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just define a pic that you place via nested loops. The coloring can be done via `\ifnum`s. The most cumbersome part is to punch in the texts from a screen shot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\definecolor{pft}{RGB}{150,198,145}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node font=\sffamily,nodes={text depth=0.25ex},
    scale=4/3,
    pics/block/.style={code={
    \tikzset{block/.cd,#1}%
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/block/##1}}%   
    \colorlet{cc}{\pv{color}}%
    \draw[fill=cc] (-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) -- 
        (\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) --
        (\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) --
        (-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=cc!70!black] (-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) -- 
        (-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2) --
        (-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2) --
        (-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=cc!60!black] (-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) -- 
        (-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2) --
        (\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2) --
        (\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) -- cycle;
    }},block/.cd,a/.initial=1,color/.initial=gray!40]
 \path[transform shape] foreach \Z in {0,...,3}
 {foreach \X in {0,...,3}
 {foreach \Y in {0,...,3}
 {\pgfextra{%
  \ifnum\Z=3
   \edef\mycolor{blue!70!black}
   \ifnum\Y=2 
    \edef\mycolor{pft}
   \fi
   \ifnum\X=1
    \ifnum\Y=2
     \edef\mycolor{orange}
    \else
     \edef\mycolor{yellow}
    \fi
   \fi      
  \else
   \edef\mycolor{gray!40}
   \ifnum\X=1 
    \edef\mycolor{yellow}
   \fi
   \ifnum\Y=2 
    \edef\mycolor{pft}
   \fi
  \fi}
 (\X,\Y,\Z) pic{block={color=\mycolor}}}}};
 % y axis
 \path foreach \X [count=\Y] in {Laptop,Mobile,TV,Tablet}
 {(-0.7,-1+\Y,3.5) node[rotate=90,anchor=south]{\X}};
 \draw[orange!30!yellow,-stealth,ultra thick] (-1.5,-0.5,3.5) -- 
  node[pos=0,sloped,above right,font=\large,black]{PRODUCTS} ++ (0,4.2,0);
 % x axis
 \path foreach \X [count=\Y] in {USA,Asia,Australia,Europe}
 {(-1+\Y,-0.7,3.5) node[anchor=north,text height=0.8em]{\X}};
 \draw[orange!30!yellow,-stealth,ultra thick] (-0.5,-1.5,3.5) --
  node[pos=0,sloped,below right,font=\large,black]{GEOGRAPHY}
  ++ (4.2,0,0);
 % z axis
 \path foreach \Y in {1,...,4}
 {(3.5,-0.5,4-\Y) node[anchor=north west,text height=0.8em]{$Q_{\Y}$}};
 \draw[orange!30!yellow,-stealth,ultra thick] (4,-1.5,3.5) --
  node[pos=0,sloped,below right,font=\large,black]{time}
  ++ (0,0,-4.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are wondering whether one can use a more realistic projection, the answer is yes.

And here is a version with full cubes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\definecolor{pft}{RGB}{150,198,145}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node font=\sffamily,nodes={text depth=0.25ex},
    scale=4/3,
    pics/block/.style={code={
    \tikzset{block/.cd,#1}%
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/block/##1}}%   
    \colorlet{cc}{\pv{color}}%
    \draw[fill=cc] (-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) -- 
        (\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) --
        (\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) --
        (-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=cc!70!black] (-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) -- 
        (-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2) --
        (-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2) --
        (-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=cc!60!black] (-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) -- 
        (-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2) --
        (\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2) --
        (\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=cc!70!black] (\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) -- 
        (\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2) --
        (\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2) --
        (\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=cc!60!black] (-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) -- 
        (-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2) --
        (\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2) --
        (\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=cc] (-\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2) -- 
        (\pv{a}/2,-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2) --
        (\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2) --
        (-\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2,\pv{a}/2) -- cycle;
    }},block/.cd,a/.initial=1,color/.initial=gray!40]
 \path[transform shape] foreach \Z in {0,...,3}
 {foreach \X in {0,...,3}
 {foreach \Y in {0,...,3}
 {\pgfextra{%
  \ifnum\Z=3
   \edef\mycolor{blue!70!black}
   \ifnum\Y=2 
    \edef\mycolor{pft}
   \fi
   \ifnum\X=1
    \ifnum\Y=2
     \edef\mycolor{orange}
    \else
     \edef\mycolor{yellow}
    \fi
   \fi      
  \else
   \edef\mycolor{gray!40}
   \ifnum\X=1 
    \edef\mycolor{yellow}
   \fi
   \ifnum\Y=2 
    \edef\mycolor{pft}
   \fi
  \fi}
 (\X,\Y,\Z) pic{block={color=\mycolor}}}}};
 % y axis
 \path foreach \X [count=\Y] in {Laptop,Mobile,TV,Tablet}
 {(-0.7,-1+\Y,3.5) node[rotate=90,anchor=south]{\X}};
 \draw[orange!30!yellow,-stealth,ultra thick] (-1.5,-0.5,3.5) -- 
  node[pos=0,sloped,above right,font=\large,black]{PRODUCTS} ++ (0,4.2,0);
 % x axis
 \path foreach \X [count=\Y] in {USA,Asia,Australia,Europe}
 {(-1+\Y,-0.7,3.5) node[anchor=north,text height=0.8em]{\X}};
 \draw[orange!30!yellow,-stealth,ultra thick] (-0.5,-1.5,3.5) --
  node[pos=0,sloped,below right,font=\large,black]{GEOGRAPHY}
  ++ (4.2,0,0);
 % z axis
 \path foreach \Y in {1,...,4}
 {(3.5,-0.5,4-\Y) node[anchor=north west,text height=0.8em]{$Q_{\Y}$}};
 \draw[orange!30!yellow,-stealth,ultra thick] (4,-1.5,3.5) --
  node[pos=0,sloped,below right,font=\large,black]{time}
  ++ (0,0,-4.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that `pgfplots` has a `3d cube` plot mark, which you could use to get similar plots in a more structured way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I remove the mini cubes and just use regular sqaures to show the division?

Comment: @Madara I do not understand the comment. This is a 3d-like picture, what you mean by squares?

Comment: Actually, forget that. I want to delete the top row. I'm trying that but it's not working. I just want three products, I tried deleting the top row draw part but it's breaking the the entire thing

Comment: The second image helps. Thanks :)